# Calling a parametrized method

Tags: java, method-call

While learning Java Generics parametrization I came up to this code:

```
public interface Comparable<T> {
    public int compareTo(T o);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

I wanted to test it, so I wrote this:

```
Integer[] iArray = new Integer[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    iArray[i] = new Integer(i);
}

int a = countGreaterThan(iArray, Integer.valueOf(5));
```

but compiler is giving me error message on last line when calling a method `countGreaterThan`:

```
The method countGreaterThan(T[], T) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[], Integer)
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.lang.Integer` does not implement the `Comparable` interface that you just wrote.

You should delete that interface and use the built-in one, which it does implement.

Comment: Oh, really... 

It was silly example I found...
Thanks!